# React Native Android Tabbar Items are not showing selection

Tags: android, react-native

I am struggling with an issue from long time. We have Tabbar in our React native app, Normally its working fine, but sometime in ANDROID device when we keep app in background and come back on app Tabbar selected state not showing all transaction is working fine, One this issue occurs after killing the app and launch again issue appear for 2-3 times, after some trail again start working well. its wired We tried having different custom tabbar lib as well, but still no luck.
[image]